# how to host .NET Remoting object in ASP.NET application?

Tags: .net, asp.net, remoting

I want my web application to return .net remoting object when somebody requests one page (or handler) with certain parameters. how to make it?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to create an instance of a Remote Object when the ASP.NET page is generated?

Doesn't this work:

```
IMyObj objMyObj = (IMyObj) Activator.GetObject(typeof(IMyObj), "http://URL/myObj.soap");
```

But perhaps I misunderstood you :)